# Qmake display names not unique, qmlscene not installed

Tags: qml, qt5, qmake, qt5.4

As you can see on the screenshot my QtCreator settings display multiple identical qmake paths.

[image: Screenshot]

My OS is UbuntuStudio and I have installed the qt5-default from the repositories.

Further on, the latest qmlscene and qmake is installed. 
According to the screenshot qmlscene is not installed?

1. Where are these information comming from? (since it is automatic)
2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean when say "he latest qmlscene and qmake is installed"? qmake is part of Qt and shouldn't be installed separately. Remove installed Qt and try to install the latest release from [http://www.qt.io/download/](http://www.qt.io/download/)

Comment: @folibis With that I mean, that the qt5-qmake and qmlscene packages according to my repository package manager are listed as installed.